# Add SQL functions to .NET Core SaveChanges method

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I am wondering if it it is possible to add SQL to the existing SaveChanges method.

In my model I have specified the fields I want to encrypt by adding a custom `Encrypted` attribute.

I found how to succesfully encrypt the data with the `IDataProtectionProvider`. 
However, it is required that the data is encrypted using SQL's `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` function.

The fieldtypes in my model are type of string (or int in some cases), I want to save them in my database as varbinary.

My question is whether it's possible to create a function that saves my entity to the db, with the needed `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` function, based on the `Encrypted` attribute specified in the model.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1. You could override `SaveChanges()` method and add logic for encrypting there.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var insert in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntityBase>()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
    {
        if (insert.Entity.Encrypted)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2. You could use a stored procedure for saving the object to database.

Comment: But could I add SQL logic to the SaveChanges method? Like wrapping the field value inside an sql statement, which the SaveChanges will include in it's transaction? If not, I'll look into the possibility of a stored procedure

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to include sql level functions in the SQL generated by save change as well